# После сообщения telegram бота не появляется клавиатура.Сообщение же приходит

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Я использую node-telegram-bot-api

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const token = ''//токен

const bot = new TelegramBot(token)


    const keyboard = [
        [
          {
            text: 'Отменить заказ', // текст на кнопке
          }
        ]
      ];
    const chatId = ; //идентификатор диалога
  
    // отправляем сообщение
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Вы успешно оставили свой заказ!',{ // клава
        inline_markup: {
            reply_keyboard: keyboard
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

В keyboard у вас нет кнопки класса InlineKeyboardButton, а только ее текст.